# `select true into bool_variable from table_name where column_name = in limit 1` vs `select column = in into bool_variable from table_name limit 1;`

Tags: sql, plsql

I'm trying to perform a PL/SQL query. The goal is to see if there is at least one row where the column, `column_name` , in `table_name` corresponds to an input value input and assign the result to bool_variable

My question is:

Does

```
select true into bool_variable from table_name where column_name = input limit 1;
```

yield the same result as

```
select column = input into bool_variable from table_name;
```

The end goal is to write an if/else condition using `bool_variable`

e.g.,

```
IF bool_variable then
   ....
END IF
```

I tried to assign a boolean variable based on result from query.

Answer (score 1):

The 1st statement is invalid, you can't select Boolean value in a `SELECT` statement (at least, not until version 23c, which you're likely not using yet). Also, there's no `LIMIT` clause in (Oracle's) PL/SQL.

```
SQL> declare
  2    bool_variable boolean;
  3  begin
  4    select true into bool_variable from dual;
  5  end;
  6  /
  select true into bool_variable from dual;
         *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-06550: line 4, column 10:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "TRUE": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 4, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

The 2nd statement is also invalid (wrong syntax), it won't work.

```
select column = input into bool_variable from table_name;
```

---

Here's example which shows one way to do that:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
  2    l_cnt         number;
  3    bool_variable boolean;
  4  begin
  5    begin
  6      select 1
  7      into l_cnt
  8      from dual
  9      where exists (select null
 10                    from dept                 --> this is your "table name"
 11                    where deptno = 99);       --> this is your "column name"
 12    exception
 13      when no_data_found then
 14        l_cnt := 0;
 15    end;
 16
 17    bool_variable := case when l_cnt = 1 then true else false end;
 18
 19    if bool_variable then
 20       dbms_output.put_line('True');
 21    else
 22       dbms_output.put_line('False');
 23    end if;
 24  end;
 25  /
False

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function to do the test:

```sql
create or replace Function
    test_count ( p_table VarChar2, p_column VarChar2, p_value VarChar2 ) Return Number IS
    BEGIN
        Declare
            m_cmd   VarChar2(255) := 'Select Count(*) From ' || p_table || ' Where To_Char(' || p_column || ') = ''' || p_value || '''';
            m_cnt   Number(6) := 0;
        Begin
            dbms_output.put_line(m_cmd);
            execute immediate m_cmd Into m_cnt;
            Return m_cnt;
        Exception
            When OTHERS Then
                Return -1;
        End;
    END test_count;
```

... and pl/sql code that will ask you to input parameters for table, column and column value to do the test with ...

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
Declare
    m_exc   EXCEPTION;
    m_bool  BOOLEAN;
    m_cnt   Number(6) := 0;
Begin
    m_cnt := test_count(p_table   => &TableName,
                        p_column  => &ColumnName,
                        p_value   => &ColumnValue);
    If m_cnt = 0 Then 
        m_bool := false;
    Elsif m_cnt > 0 Then
        m_bool := true;
    ElsIf m_cnt = -1 Then 
        RAISE m_exc;
    End If;
    --
    If m_bool Then
        dbms_output.put_line('True');
    Else
        dbms_output.put_line('False');
    End If;
Exception
    When m_exc Then
        dbms_output.put_line('Function test_count() errored!');
End;
/
```

```sql
/* Result for p_table = 'EMP'  /  p_column = 'DEPTNO'  /  p_value = 30
Select Count(*) From EMP Where To_Char(DEPTNO) = '30'
True
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.    */
```

```sql
/* Result for p_table = 'EMP'  /  p_column = 'DEPTNO'  /  p_value = 110
Select Count(*) From EMP Where To_Char(DEPTNO) = '110'
False
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.    */
```

```sql
/* Result for p_table = 'XXX'  /  p_column = 'YYY'  /  p_value = 9
Select Count(*) From XXX Where To_Char(YYY) = '9'
Function test_count() errored!
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.    */
```

... Test with SQL

```sql
WITH
    depts AS
        ( Select 10 "DEPTNO" From Dual Union All
          Select 30 "DEPTNO" From Dual Union All
          Select 110 "DEPTNO" From Dual )
Select  DEPTNO, 
        Case When test_count(p_table  => 'EMP', 
                             p_column => 'DEPTNO', 
                             p_value  => DEPTNO) > 0 
             Then 'True' 
        Else 'False' 
        End "TEST_RESULT"
From    depts
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
    DEPTNO TEST_RESULT
---------- -----------
        10 True 
        30 True 
       110 False       */
```